# What is the correct way of DateListPlot-ting multiple data sets at once?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

In Mathematica 10.1 I could do the following:

```
sunrises = {{#, 0}, {#, 5}} & /@ {1514790039, 1514876410, 1514962776, 1515049137};
DateListPlot[sunrises, Joined -> True]
ListPlot[sunrises, Joined -> True]
```

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

But since Mathematica 11 `DateListPlot` seems to behave differently:

> DateListPlot::ldata: {{{1514790039,0},{1514790039,5}},{{1514876410,0},{1514876410,5}},{{1514962776,0},{1514962776,5}},{{1515049137,0},{1515049137,5}}} is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.

Apparently, the `ListPlot`-like syntax is no longer acceptable. So what is the "official" way to achieve this? Or is it simply a bug which should be reported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug introduced in Mathematica 11.0.1, persisting in 11.1.0, and fixed as of 11.2.0.

Comment: Did you solve the problem (or bug): `DateListPlot::ldata: <|Bhutan->Missing[KeyAbsent,Bhutan],Kiribati->Missing[KeyAbsent,Kiribati],Vanuatu->Missing[KeyAbsent,Vanuatu]|>` is not a valid dataset or list of datasets. I face the same problem with version 11.3.

Comment: @TugrulTemel your dataset indeed doesn't appear to be valid for `DateListPlot`. This function needs a list, rather than an association, and the abscissa values should be dates, rather than variables without value.

Comment: Do you have an idea for fixing the problem. Maybe I can show you the database created to see the data format. I appreciate your reply.

Comment: @TugrulTemel your problem seems to be independent of this question. It's more appropriate to make a new question, rather than chat in comments to this answer.